# how to set focus on jquery confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a simple jquery confirm dialog and wants to set focus on dialog itself rather on any other element. code below is what i did to set focus on:

```
function showAlert() {   

                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    title: 'Main Information',
                    resizable: false,
                    height:140,
                    modal: true,
                    closeOnEscape:true,
                    buttons: {        
                        "Yes": function() {
                            document.getElementById('form1:newProfile' ).value="true";
                            if(disableSaveFlag) return false; else disableEnableSaveBtn('true');
                               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        },
                        "No": function() {
                            document.getElementById('form1:newProfile' ).value="false";
                            if(disableSaveFlag) return false; else disableEnableSaveBtn('true');
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }      
                    }    
                });
                 $("#dialog-confirm").focus(); // this line sets focus on div element with given id
            }

<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display:none">  
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        Do you want to create a new profile ? 
    </p>
</div>
```

problem is i cannot find "Id" of a dialog itself to being focus on to it.
As a result focus is set on Div element and my title is not focused.

below is what i get with above code:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "focus" a div?

Comment: you need a input type tag for the focus. a button or something. you can't focus a div.

Comment: @TheBrain Google "Javascript focus a div" - you'll get results that I've never heard of

Comment: i have just added a screen shot please refer to it, required result is the second one where tilte is also shown. basically i have focused on a div that i have added for showing my own text.how to get focus on the outer div that is created by ".dialog" dynaically....

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and it will focus the first element of the dialog.

Comment: I think the idea was to find a jquery solution to avoid having to do this. Also, how would you do this with a non-input element?

Comment: I have a Jquery Confirm dialog with just a button (OK) to acknowledge after certain ajax function. I also was searching for how to set focus on the button, so that user can just press 'Enter' to close it. Pressing 'Tab' helped me, it directly focus the button.

If there is a non-input element, is there a point of focusing on it?

Comment: I don't think there's a point to focusing on the div element, but that's what the question's asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can focus anything on below event. I just tried and working fine for me..

```
onContentReady: function () {
    //select the element you want to focus here
    $(".btn-success").focus();
}
```

So my full code looks like this. In this case I am focusing the Button on my dialog.

```
$.confirm({
    icon: "fas fa-check-square",
    title: "&nbsp;Completed!",
    content: "Action Plans Updated Successfully!",
    type: "green",
    typeAnimated: true
    buttons: {
    Complete: {
      text: "Complete",
      btnClass: "btn-success",
      action: function () {
        location.reload(true);
      },
    },
  },
  onContentReady: function () {
      $(".btn-success").focus();
  },
});
```